# Figma - Change font family on all instances

Tags: figma

Goal: Change font family, and apply new font family to all instances.

Ex: On the image bellow, the Open sans text is set as a component, and the weights, are set as an instance of the component.

[image]

Then I wanted to change to another font family, and have the instances reflected that change, showing the new font family with corresponding font weights:
[image]

Challenge: If I set everything as font styles (headers, body, etc), then I need to manually one by one when I  want to test a new font. That is why would be convent to have a master component that sets the font family and passes that to all typography system.

Question: How can I add instances that change according to the font family?

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question correctly but do you mean something like: `body * { font-family: your-font; }` ?

Comment: nope, I just need to change the font family on the component  master, and have all instances also changed